# Maven and IntelliJ modular project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have two dependencies one of them is built on top of the other.
The first project is with POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.site</groupId>
<artifactId>site</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

This project is built on top of another project (dependence)
which have the following POM

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

How can I import these two projects in Intellij so when i make changes in sources in the platform project, these projects two be available in site project.

I have access to both depositories and their sources.

Best regards.

Comment: I don't usually do this.  I would package the independent project as a JAR and publish it to a Maven repo.  The dependent project would simply import it as a dependency and use it.  I'd have the two maintained and versioned independently.  I don't know if that works for your use case, but it's great for mine.

Comment: Ok, but the project is Spring boot (website) so I want to debug some things "realtime" and to view changes directly in the view for example?

Comment: If you use IntelliJ you can debug in dependencies without that complexity.  Open the dependent class and set a breakpoint.  If they are truly two separate runtimes you'll need to run each one in its own IntelliJ instance.  You can still set breakpoints.  I've got as many as three running at the same time on my local machine.  I would not make them one project.  They are separate; treat them that way.

Comment: Ok, what about if I want to put new model object in the view. Models are in the other project. I want to know fast is this model working correctly in the view or not.

Comment: Create that package in the dependent project and put the model object in it.  Make sure that it's working in the view.  Once it's all set you can decide if it still belongs in the dependent project or if you want to migrate it to the independent one and repackage.  Not hard.

Comment: Hmm, You mean that I have to "override" the class in the dependent project, and if it works, I should put this implementation in the original jar ?

Comment: No.  You said "new model".  That sounded like a new class to me.  Put it in the package that makes sense.  If it's not shared by other apps, you could choose to keep it only in the dependent project.  Otherwise move it to the independent, shared JAR.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have 2 projects (instead of a single multi-module project) it's really quite simple - open two intellij windows, one for `site` and one for `platform`.

Next, you need to define group and version for `platform`.

```
<groupId>com.company.platform</groupId>
<artifactId>platform</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Now update the pom for `site` with the `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` version for `platform` dependency.

Your workflow is like this:

- make change in platform project, use `Maveh Projects` window to build (`clean install`)
- switch to `site` project, which depends on `platform-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, use `Maven Projects` window to `Reimport all Maven Projects`

You should then see the code updates from `platform` in `site` project.

When you want to go in production you need to go from `-SNAPSHOT` to release (non-snapshot) dependencies.